# Goroutine safe channel close doesn't actually close webscoket

Tags: go, websocket, channel, goroutine, binance

This one is a tricky issue that bugs me quite a bit.

Essentially, I wrote an integration microservice that provides data streams from Binance crypto exchange using the Go client. A client sends a start messages, starts data stream for a symbol, and at some point, sends a close message to stop the stream. My implementation looks basically like this:

```golang
func (c BinanceClient) StartDataStream(clientType bn.ClientType, symbol, interval string) error {
    
    switch clientType {

    case bn.SPOT_LIVE:
        wsKlineHandler := c.handlers.klineHandler.SpotKlineHandler
        wsErrHandler := c.handlers.klineHandler.ErrHandler

        _, stopC, err := binance.WsKlineServe(symbol, interval, wsKlineHandler, wsErrHandler)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return err
        } else {
            c.state.clientSymChanMap[clientType][symbol] = stopC
            return nil
        }
  ... 
}
```

The clientSymChanMap stores the stopChannel in a nested hashmap so that I can retrieve the stop channel later to stop the data feed. The stop function has been implemented accordingly:

```golang
func (c BinanceClient) StopDataStream(clientType bn.ClientType, symbol string) {
    //mtd := "StopDataStream: "

    stopC := c.state.clientSymChanMap[clientType][symbol]

    if isClosed(stopC) {
        DbgPrint(" Channel is already closed. Do nothing for: " + symbol)
    } else {
        close(stopC)
    }
    // Delete  channel from the map otherwise the next StopAll throws a NPE due to closing a dead channel
    delete(c.state.clientSymChanMap[clientType], symbol)
    return
}
```

To prevent panics from already closed channels, I use a check function that returns true in case the channel is already close.

```golang
func isClosed(ch <-chan struct{}) bool {
    select {
    case <-ch:
        return true
    default:
    }
    return false
}
```

Looks nice, but has a catch. When I run the code with starting data for just one symbol, it starts and closes the datafeed exactly as expected.

However, when starting multiple data feeds, then the above code somehow never closes the websocket and just keeps streaming data forever. Without the isClosed check, I get panics of trying to close a closed channel, but with the check in place, well, nothing gets closed.

When looking at the [implementation of the above binance.WsKlineServe](https://github.com/adshao/go-binance/blob/master/v2/websocket.go) function, it's quite obvious that it just wraps a new websocket with each invocation and then returns the done & stop channel.

The documentation gives the following usage example:

```golang
wsKlineHandler := func(event *binance.WsKlineEvent) {
    fmt.Println(event)
}
errHandler := func(err error) {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
doneC, stopC, err := binance.WsKlineServe("LTCBTC", "1m", wsKlineHandler, errHandler)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
<-doneC
```

Because the doneC channel actually blocks, I removed it and thought that storing the stopC channel and then use it later to stop the datafeed would work. However, it only does so for one single instance. When multiple streams are open, this doesn't work anymore.

Any idea what that's the case and how to fix it?

Comment: Seems that package `go-binance` could be improved. It should use a cancellable context instead to close a running process as that abstracts away the complexity of close channels.

Comment: @tehSpinx, can you post a link or some resources about correct usage of cancellable context? I have a handful of those unpleasant websockets ...

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using channels for stopping a goroutine or closing something is very tricky. There are lots of things you can do wrong or forget to do.

`context.WithCancel` abstracts that complexity away, making the code more readable and maintainable.

Some code snippets:

```
ctx, cancel := context.WitchCancel(context.TODO())
TheThingToCancel(ctx, ...)

// Whenever you want to stop TheThingToCancel. Can be called multiple times.
cancel()
```

Then in a for loop you'd often have a `select` like this:

```
for {
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return
    default:
    }

    // do stuff
}
```

Here some code that is closer to your specific case of an open connection:

```
func TheThingToCancel(ctx context.Context) (context.CancelFunc, error) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)

    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", ":12345")
    if err != nil {
        cancel()
        return nil, err
    }

    go func() {
        <-ctx.Done()
        _ = conn.Close()
    }()

    go func() {
        defer func() {
            _ = conn.Close()
            // make sure context is always cancelled to avoid goroutine leak
            cancel()
        }()

        var bts = make([]byte, 1024)
        for {
            n, err := conn.Read(bts)
            if err != nil {
                return
            }
            fmt.Println(bts[:n])
        }
    }()

    return cancel, nil
}
```

It returns the `cancel` function to be able to close it from the outside.

Cancelling a context can be done many times over without a `panic` like would occur if a channel is closed multiple times. That is one advantage. Also you can derive contexts from other contexts and thereby close a lot of contexts that all stop different routines by closing a parent context. Carefully designed, this is very powerful for shutting down different routines belonging together that also need to be able to be shut down individually.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, this is dangerous:

```
if isClosed(stopC) {
    DbgPrint(" Channel is already closed. Do nothing for: " + symbol)
} else {
    close(stopC) // <- can't be sure channel is still open
}
```

there is no guarantee that after your polling check of the channel state, that the channel will still be in that same state in the next line of code. So this code could in theory could panic if it's called concurrently.

---

If you want an asynchronous action to occur on the channel close - it's best to do this explicitly from its own goroutine. So you could try this:

```
go func() {

    stopC := c.state.clientSymChanMap[clientType][symbol]
    <-stopC
    // stopC definitely closed now
    delete(c.state.clientSymChanMap[clientType], symbol)
}()
```

---

P.S. you do need some sort of mutex on your map, since the delete is asynchronous - you need to ensure any adds to the map don't datarace with this.

P.P.S Channels are reclaimed by the GC when they go out of scope. If you are no longer reading from it - they do not need to be explicitly closed to be reclaimed by the GC.

Comment: Thank you, I will patch the code tomorrow (It's late here in Asia) and post an update. Thanks for the idea of the separate close goroutine. That makes it a quite practical solution.

Comment: This worked out of the box and  solved the problem. I mean, there is some other snafu i.e. missing mutex, but having all those panics off the plate really helps. Again, thank you.

Comment: Note that the goroutine that calls `delete` should be the same goroutine that was started in order to process the stream in the call to `StartDataStream`. Otherwise, it too can end up racy — consider what happens if you have multiple calls to `StopDataStream` interleaving with multiple calls to `StartDataStream` for the same `clientType`.

Comment: @bcmills I had the same thought - it really should be done at the call site. And that would simplify the add/delete logic of the map.